# Cannot find class [com.springdemo] for bean with name 'helloworld' defined in class path resource [bean.xml]

Tags: xml, spring

I am just starting spring framework and tried "Hello world" tutorial from this [site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm).
I have **Mainapp.Java** as

```
package com.springdemo;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
        Hello_World obj = (Hello_World)context.getBean("helloworld");
        obj.getMessage();
        }
}
```

**Hello_World.java**

```
package com.springdemo;

public class Hello_World {

    private String message;
    public void setMessage(String message){
    this.message = message;
    }
    public void getMessage(){
    System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
    }
}
```

and **bean.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
<bean id="helloworld" class="com.springdemo">
<property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.springdemo] for bean with name 'helloworld' defined in class path resource [bean.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springdemo
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:787)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:369)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:66)
    at com.springdemo.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springdemo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:381)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1170)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: You're missing the class name in the bean definition. Should be `<bean id="helloworld" class="com.springdemo.Hello_World">`

Answer (score 3):

I added a file extension to the class `org.stuff.Triangle.java` in the xml file instead of the fully-qualified class name.

This is the right way for my code:

```
        <bean id="triangle" class="org.stuff.Triangle"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

of course @c.P.u1 has already given the answer other way out (auto detection) you can try is

1. Remove your explicit bean declaration
2. Annotate your class `Hello_World` with `@Component`
3. Use `<annotation-driven />` in your configuration file
4. Provide bean detection configuration using `<context:component-scan base-package="com.springdemo" />`

Answer (score 0):

update bean.xml

```html
<bean id="helloworld" class="com.springdemo.Hello_World">
    <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to add the class location in bean.xml
For your case Hello_World class is the class that return the value so just call this class.

```
<bean id="helloworld" class="com.springdemo.Hello_World">
   <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
</bean>
```

One more thing I noticed in your code. In the main class You must write the getBean(Bean ID value)

So I think the right one should be:

```
Hello_World message= (Hello_World)appContext.getBean("helloworld");
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginner here as well and I went through several posts and about 30 min but I am using IntelliJ instead of the recommended IDE.  I have the Hello_World and MainApp in src/main/java and the beans in src/main/resources.  I finally figured out that the class needed no prefix for location.  I know this isn't directly linked to this question but it was top on the google list when searching error messages.

```
<bean id = "helloWorld" class = "Hello_World">
    <property name = "message" value = "Hello World!"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the bean tag the class parameter should contain full class name path.You have not written class name.
Instead of this 
bean id="helloworld" class="com.springdemo"

write this 
bean id="helloworld" class="com.springdemo.Hello_World"